# How to convert 8.weeks to "8 weeks" in Ruby easily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby you can have `8.weeks` which is of type `ActiveSupport::Duration`.  How can I convert that to string `'8 weeks'` easily?  Preferably without doing the math of converting weeks to seconds then dividing it by the number of seconds in a week.

Also, how can I convert `50.days` to string `'7 weeks and 1 day'` easily?  Notice I am not using "month" here, also preferably without doing calculation of seconds in math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part:

`8.weeks.inspect # => "8 weeks"`

For the second part:

`((50.days / 1.week).weeks + (50.days % 1.week)).inspect # => "7 weeks and 1 day"`

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly the answer I'm looking for!  Not sure why the self-appointed mandarins closed this question!

Answer (score 0):

> In Ruby you can have 8.weeks which is of type ActiveSupport::Duration.

This is not implemented by Ruby but a monkey patch provided by ActiveSupport.

As you already use ActiveSupport I expect you want to use this in combination with Rails. You could use the `distance_of_time_in_words` helper. It's a view helper so it's a bit of a pain though.

```rb
ApplicationController.helpers.distance_of_time_in_words(8.weeks)
# -> about two months
```

If you need more details, have a look at the implementations and adapt to your needs. Depending on your needs, you might need to handle i18n as well so might turn out rather complicated.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L95

Answer (score 0):

In a Rails console

```
8.weeks
=> 8 weeks
```